# How to rotate elements with SVG Salamander

Tags: java, svg, svg-salamander

I use SVG Salamander to display and manipulate SVG images in Java. I managed to change fill, stroke or text of elements and display the changes.

Now I want to rotate an element. So I tried to manipulate the transformation matrix:

```
SVGElement e = diagram.getElement("path4150");
System.out.println(e.getPresAbsolute("transform").getStringValue());
StyleAttribute t = e.getPresAbsolute("transform");
double[] d = t.getDoubleList();
d[0] = -0.39394618;
d[1] = -0.91913346;
d[2] = 0.91913357;
d[3] = -0.39394618;
d[4] = -429.42706;
d[5] = 1513.019;
t.setStringValue("matrix(" + Joiner.on(",").join(Doubles.asList(d)) + ")");
System.out.println(e.getPresAbsolute("transform").getStringValue());
diagram.render(graphics);
```

Output:

> matrix(0.87615346,0.48203226,-0.48203232,0.87615346,468.09264,-25.725313)
>   matrix(-0.39394618,-0.91913346,0.91913357,-0.39394618,-429.42706,1513.019)

As I can see in the output, the matrix is changed. But the element is not rotating in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I just started learning about this - but the SVGSalamander doc mentioned one needs to call updateTime() on a container of the element that is modified (or maybe just the root element?), to force it to redraw.  If you're not using animation, then any value (0.0?) as an argument to updateTime() would do...